# How to use recaptcha in WordPress realia plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, recaptcha

I am a beginner in WordPress and want to add recaptcha into the create-property page of homelist theme.
I noticed that there is "class-realia-recaptcha.php" file in realia plugin but I don't know how to use it to show recaptcha on the create-property page.
If someone knows and has experience in homelist theme and this issue, please help me.
Thank you.
https://github.com/PragmaticMates/realia/tree/master/includes

Answer (score 0):

add this (reCaptcha by BestWebSoft) plugin in your WP  it is an effective security solution that protects your WordPress website forms from spam entries while letting real people pass through with ease.